# Spark to_json operation to Java converstion

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Consider the following line:

```
var pt = ... .select(col("patientid"), to_json(struct("*")) as "resource")
```

What does this operation do?

Does this mean that it takes up a list JSON objects and convert it to one column as "resource"?

How would this code be written in Java?

Comment: If this resembles any sort sql-like syntax at all (I'm unfamiliar with this), then `to_json(struct("*"))` I'd expect to take whole row of some underlying result set and convert it to Json. Query overall would then produce a result set with two columns: "patientid" and "resource", first containing some identifier, and second containing a JSONObject.

Comment: Cool.! Clears some part of it. Thanks. Any idea how to go about this in Java?

Comment: I'm not claiming I know how it works or how to convert it. I'm only saying what it looks like it does to me. So, unfortunately, I won't be able to help with Java part.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov is correct. And you have the same function present in the JAVA API as well.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation @philantrovert. Any link for this JavaAPI specifically for "to_json"? *couldn't find any*